# Factorization of Square-integrable random-variables and Generalized Inverses

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inverse, inverse-function, pseudoinverse

Suppose that $X,Y,Z \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P};\mathbb{R}^d)$, are $d$-dimensional random-vectors and there exists functions $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),Law(X);\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfying
$$
f(X)=Y \qquad g(X)=Z.
$$

If $f$ is invertible, then the function $h\triangleq g\circ f^{-1}$ implies that
$$
Z=h(Y).
$$

However, if $f$ is *not* invertible, when does there exists a function $h$ satisfying
$
h\circ f = g
$
except possibly on a set of $Law(X)$-measure $0$?  Hence
$$
h(Y)=Z
.
$$

Comment: The law of $X$ is a measure on the Borel sets of $\Bbb R^d$. Something does not add up here.

Comment: Thanks, made it clear now :)

Comment: The space $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},Law(X);\mathbb{R}^d)$ still doesn't make sense. ;-)

Comment: Should be good now, thanks for noticing that; I fixed it to the Borel measure space on $d$-dimensional Euclidean space.  :)